# Windows IoT Core project build fails with 'MSB3774: Could not find SDK "WindowsIoT..."'

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

After updating my project to Windows SDK 17763 I can no longer build my Windows IoT Core project.  The error is MSB3774: Could not find SDK "WindowsIoT…"

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this error go to the Solution Explorer, expand References, and delete the "Windows IoT Extension SDK" reference.

Starting in 17763, the contents of the WindowsIoT extension are included in the Universal contract, so the WindowsIoT extension is no longer needed.